# How to connect to a Nodejs backend from Vue FrontEnd Using Axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, nodemailer

I want to send Email via a contact form in the frontend, then communicate with the node backend with i have created and send to a particular gmail

I created an email service then i did the following:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3000';

class EmailService {
   sendEmail(url, data) {
      return axios.post(url, data)
   }
}

export default EmailService;
```

Then in my Contact.vue template i imported EmailService and also created a method called sendMessage()

```
sendMessage() {
      this.loading = true;
      const contact = {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        message: this.message
      };

      this.contact = EmailService
        .sendEmail("http://localhost:3000/sendmail", contact)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            let res = data;
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(`${contact.name} has send a mail`, res);
            this.snackbar = true;
            this.loading = false;
            this.$refs.form.reset();
          },
          err => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(err);
            this.snackbarError = true;
          }
        );
```

Error i got:

`vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _emailService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.sendEmail is not a function"`

and it does not send anything

who knows what's wrong?

Comment: You need an instance of your class, not just the class itself. Try `export default new EmailService()`

Comment: Mark the methods as static `static sendEmail(url, data)`.
Or why don't you declare your methods whitout using a class and export the "service" as an object.

```
    const sendEmail = (url, data)  => // method declaration
    export const emailService  = {sendEmail};
```